# SQLiteException syntax error on line breaks trying to read dump file from assets

Tags: android, sqlite, assets

I'm developing an `Android` app which in I have a `SQLite` dump file in *assets* and I'm trying to create a database in user's phone using that dump.

The problem is it's a long dump file containing sql command including line breaks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [tblType] (
  [IdType] INTEGER NOT NULL ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK PRIMARY KEY ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK AUTOINCREMENT, 
  [Type] NVARCHAR);
```

So when I try to create the database using `SQLiteOpenHelper`:

```
SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper0 = new DbHelper(this);

Cursor cu = null;
try {
    cu = openHelper0.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select IdWord,Word from tblWord", null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get syntax error on every line including a line break:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code
>   1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE [tblType](

And if I remove the first line break I get:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code
>   1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE [tblType]([IdType] INTEGER NOT
>   NULL ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK PRIMARY KEY ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK
>   AUTOINCREMENT,

As I said, it's a large dump and I can't manually remove all linebreaks; So the question is is there any way like configurations or extra code to make `Android` ignores the line breaks?

This is the main code from `DBHelper`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    try {
        InputStream is = activity.getAssets().open("am.sql");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\n");

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(scanner.next());
        }
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException ex){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the file line by line. This does not work for SQL statements having multiple lines.

You can use a semicolon at the end of a line to detect the actual end of statements, if you do not have any SQL statements that contain embedded semicolons (triggers, or text values with a semicolon before a newline).

Comment: What if I had some `;` in table contents?

Comment: Immediately followed by a newline? Then you'd have to parse the SQL.

Comment: So if `;` in content doesn't followed by new line, can I use `;\n`  as a Delimiter like `new Scanner(is).useDelimiter(";\n");`?

Comment: That's what my answer says.